# What is happening under the covers in this scala code?

Tags: scala

I have the following scala code (from the FP In Scala book):

```
import scala.{Option => _, Either => _, Left => _, Right => _, _} // hide std library `Option` and `Either`, since we are writing our own in this chapter

case class Left[+E](get: E) extends Either[E,Nothing]
case class Right[+A](get: A) extends Either[Nothing,A]

sealed trait Either[+E,+A] {
 def map[B](f: A => B): Either[E, B] = this match {
   case Right(r) => Right(f(r))
   case Left(e) => Left(e)
 }

 def flatMap[EE >: E, B](f: A => Either[EE, B]): Either[EE, B] = this match {
   case Right(r) => f(r)
   case Left(e) => Left(e)
 }

 def map2[EE >: E, B, C](b: Either[EE, B])(f: (A, B) => C): Either[EE, C] = {
    this flatMap(aa => b map (bb => f(aa, bb)))
 }

}
```

I would like to know what is going on when I call map2 like this:

```
val b = fpinscala.errorhandling.Right(2)
val a = fpinscala.errorhandling.Right("right")
val f = (a: String, b:Int) => a + b
a.map2(b)(f)
```

How does scala know to use substitute `this` (i.e. `a`) into the `aa` in this line of code: `this flatMap(aa => b map (bb => f(aa, bb)))` in the `map2` function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read this flatMap code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34033746/how-to-read-this-flatmap-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jcm, see if this makes any sense.

```
a.map2(b)(f)
```

We're calling the `map2` method of the `a` object. Inside the method code `a` is now referenced as `this`.

```
this flatMap(aa => b map (bb => f(aa, bb)))
```

Now we're calling the `flatMap` method of the `this` object (which is still `a`).

What does `flatMap` take as an argument?  It takes a function, a function that takes an argument (of some type that we'll refer to as "A") and returns an `Either`.  So that means that everything between the parentheses is that function.  That function has no name (i.e. no `def` statement) so it's often called an anonymous function.

That function takes an argument. This code `aa =>` identifies the argument so that it can be referred to later in the function.  "aa" is just an arbitrary name. We could have used "thisthat" or "xyz".

Where does the value that `aa` contains come from?  It comes out of `this`.  Consider the following code.

```
List(4,7,9).map(x => 42 - x)
```

In this case `map` invokes the anonymous function three times, once for every value from the List. `x` takes on a new value (first 4, then 7, then 9) every time the function is invoked.

If that all makes any sense then apply the same logic to `b map (bb => .....)` and you're almost home!

Answer (score 0):

> How does scala know to use substitute `this` (i.e. `a`) into the `aa`

`aa` is not replaced with `this`. `aa` is replaced with the string `"right"`.

The replacement is done by `flatMap` here:

```
case Right(r) => f(r)
```

`flatMap` checks if this instance of `Either` is a `Right` or a `Left`. If it is a `Right`, then it feeds its content (the string `"right"`) into the function `f` (`aa => b map (bb => f(aa, bb))`).

Answer (score 0):

> How does scala know to use substitute this (i.e. a) into the aa in
>   this line of code: this flatMap(aa => b map (bb => f(aa, bb))) in the
>   map2 function?

It is not. What is going on here is this:

1. A closure is being built, which takes an `Either[EE,B]`, calls it `aa` and computes `b map (bb => f(aa, bb)`. `b` and `f` are taken from the parent scope.
2. `this.flatMap` is being called, given that function as a parameter.

Read more on Scala closures :-)